# Idiom or short phrase to describe something that you've made roughly but only by yourself

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom or short phrase that describes the following idea: (eg code for [Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)):

*Maybe it’s rough and worse than the others, but **I did it by myself** and it works*

Do-it-yourself feature is main for this case!
I need emphasize that it's not a port, copy, rewriting or similar.

Comment: See [kludge](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377125/is-kludge-a-proper-word-to-name-a-dirty-hack-in-software-development), [formal euphemism for hack](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221123/what-can-be-used-as-formal-euphemism-of-hack), [word for making a shoddy version](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553841/is-there-a-word-for-making-a-shoddy-version-of-something-just-to-get-it-working), [created recklessly for temporary use](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381192/does-a-word-meaning-created-recklessly-for-temporary-use-exist)

Comment: The latest edits change the question entirely; this should probably be made into a separate question.

Comment: What is a codegolf?

Comment: @David please see link added to the OP. It is like "hole in one" for competitive programmers.

Answer (score 3):

You are describing what you have created as "my **lash-up**". Definitions vary but all describe something put together in a rough and ready manner to do the job but to lack elegance or reliability.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lash-up)
> *lash-up*:
> something hastily put together or improvised

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lash-up)
> *lash-up*:
> a temporary connection of equipment for experimental or emergency use

The origin of the phrase lies in tying (lashing) things together sufficiently well for their combination just to be able to perform its task. Here is one explanation of the origin:

> [Phrases](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/60/messages/7.html?utm_content=cmp-true)
> *Its literal meaning is to secure something with ropes as a temporary repair or to stop an item from going adrift during bad weather. Figurative -- "a hurried expediency, a badly performed job or complete disorganization." From "Salty Dog Talk: The Nautical Origins of Everyday Expressions" by Bill Beavis and Richard G. McCloskey (Sheridan House, Dobbs Ferry, N.Y., 1995. First published in Great Britain, 1983). Page 46.*

Comment: Hmm _just my lash-up_ sounds good!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers linked in comment, I suggest

> **rough and ready**
> Unpolished, imperfect, or unkempt, but generally able or ready for use or action.
> Somewhat lacking in refinement, sophistication, manners, etc.

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Rough+and+Ready).

Comment: I know it's not the thing to comment when one has answered oneself, but where in "rough and ready" is there the "I did it by myself" demanded in the question?

Comment: @David - The original question was unclear and did not emphasize that the 'I did it by myself' feature was important. It was only after multiple edits that that was made clear.

Answer (score 2):

The edited question seeks phrasing for

> Maybe it’s rough and worse than the others, but **I did it by myself** and it works

I propose

- . . . my [brainchild](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brainchild) works.
- . . . it is all my own work.

Answer (score 1):

> **“an ill-favoured thing, sir, but mine own”**

[*Shakespeare: As You Like It: Act 5, Scene 4*](https://shakespeare-navigators.com/as_you_like_it/As_You_Like_It_Act_5_Scene_4.html)

Certainly the idiom or phrase of greatest vintage and familiar to all educated English-speakers. I would make the reservation that it can be used for possessions, not necessarily objects one has constructed.